# Saving class instance to a file and access it from another project

Tags: c#, class, project, binaryfiles

I am trying to build a program with a lot of data. I want the data to be read from a binary file. This is realy easy to do using the BinaryFormatter.

my problem is that I want to create the data file from another project.

Here is how it works: I have a mini project that lets me edit the data in the file and it has class named "Data" which stores a string with data, and a reference to another class. I am creating an instance to the class and saving it to the file.

In the main project I also have a copy of class "Data". when I read from the file, I can't cast the data I have read to type "Data" (although it is exactly the same, just different file).

I have tried to delete the copy and add the class as link from the mini-project, but got the same results…

The last thing I tried was to create a project with the Data class, make it as dll file and add reference to it in the project,
but I got the following error "The type object is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandart, Version=2.0.0.0,…".

Any idea how can I achieve that¿

Comment: Don't use a copy of the class. Put the class in a shared assembly, so you can access it across projects.

Comment: how do I do it¿ I am pretty new to visual studio and c#

Comment: Add a new project to your solution of type Class Library, move your Data class to that project, and reference it in your original projects.

Comment: done that, but in my original projects i get error that class Data doesn't exist.
I tried add using, but it doesn't find the namespace

Comment: Right click "References" - add reference - Projects - Solutions - check your new assembly

Comment: that what i did, but when I type the class name the auto completion doesn't find the class. The error i get is "the type or name space 'Data' could not be found, Are you missing an assembly reference?"

Comment: and I can see my project added to the references

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177617/discussion-between-pritaeas-and-user9977758).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a new project in you solution as a shared library (.DLL) Your class you are encoding/decoding should be in that library and then both projects should include that library.

This way both projects have references to the same class so can encode/decode to/from it.